# Unable to align a text and a Switch in a Row lambda in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

**ISSUE**

I am trying to align the text `Enable Notifications` and the switch on the same line. If I were to use XML layouts, then I would have gone with constraint layout, but I am trying to figure out how to do this with Compose.

**SET UP**

```
@Composable
fun Settings() {
    val viewModel: SettingsViewModel = viewModel()
    val uiState: SettingsState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value
    SettingsList(uiState = uiState, viewModel)
}

@Composable
fun SettingsList(uiState: SettingsState, viewModel: SettingsViewModel, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier, scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier.semantics {
                    heading()
                },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 12.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.header_settings_back)
                )
                Spacer(modifier = modifier.width(16.dp))
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.header_settings),
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
                )
            }
        }
    ) {
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(scrollState).padding(paddingValues = it)
        ) {
            NotificationSettingsComposable(uiState.notificationsEnabled, {
                viewModel.toggleNotificationSettings()
            }, Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NotificationSettingsComposable(checked: Boolean, onCheckedChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(modifier = modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.body_enable_notifications), fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
            )
            Switch(checked = checked, onCheckedChange = onCheckedChanged, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Top))
        }
    }
}
```

However the text and the switch are not being aligned on the same line.

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

The text and the switch should be aligned on the same line as shown in this picture.

**This is what I am getting**

[image: Text and Switch are not aligned in a row]

**What I want to achieve**

[image: Text and Switch are horizontally aligned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically` in the Row:

Something like:

```
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Text(
        text = "Enable Notification", fontSize = 16.sp,
    )

    Switch(
        checked = checkedState.value,
        onCheckedChange = { checkedState.value = it }
    )
}
```

[image]